# TimePicker is not scrollable?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm making a Modal with TimePicker inside it. But the TimePicker Pop up doesn't have horizontal scroll bar, so it's like:
[image]

```js
// here is my sample code
<div id="modal">
 <Modal>
  <Form>
   <Form.Item>
    <div id='time'>
     <TimePicker defaultValue={...} getPopupContainer={triggerNode => triggerNode.parentNode as HTMLElement/>
    </div>
   </Form.Item>
  </Form>
 </Modal>
</div>
```

I had searched on google and tried to add prop `getPopupContainer={triggerNode => triggerNode.parentNode}` and `getPopupContainer={() => document.getElementById('time')}` but both of them is not working, same result. even get id `modal`. Anyone know what happen? Thanks

My expected: [image]

Comment: ```css```  apply height and overflowY property on the picker

Comment: it break style of antd, actually my expected is the default style of TimePicker, I don't know why my TimePicker is broken.

Comment: Can you provide *all* the relevant code, i.e. `Modal`, `Form`, `TimePicker` and associated CSS? If you can also provide a **running** [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example in a codesandbox it may be easier to repro and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem! I have some css variable override global style of Ant Design. I removed and it's work. Thank for your help.